# Core Data sort by auto increment Index?

Tags: ios, core-data

### Core Data sort by auto increment Index?

I have googled Core Data don't have an auto increment id explicitly. 
So there is no way sort by the auto-increment ID without self implement coding 
(this easily done in sqlite3 directly).

### WHAT I HAVE FOUND

**ObjectID : but there is no auto-increment ID.**
**NSSortedSet : iOS 5.0/OS X 10.7+, not a good idea

### OR I have to do this

**add an attribute like entityID,and set it in code then safe

### My Trouble in App

Four answers A,B,C,D for a question, the answers are Sequential.I am thinking add entityID and set an increment value for it. then I use it for SORT

```
@interface NSQuestion : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * questionID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *answers; 
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSAnswer *selectedAnswer;
@end
```

### Addition

I exported the model NSQuestion from xcdatamodeld,*I am wandering why it is NSSet *answers rather than NSArray answer*

### GOOD WAY?

if any other have same question like this one, what's your really solution?

Comment: Core Data generates an NSSet as a property on your NSManagedObject subclass to represent a to-many relationship between this and another entity. If you want your values as an array, you can get it like so:
NSArray *answerArray = [[self answers] allObjects];

Comment: but NSSet is unordered  collection. the key point is ORDER.

Comment: That was meant as a response to your additional query, not an answer to your main question. As far as the actual sorting, NSManagedObject and its subclasses have a property objectID. You could use that to sort. Or give each object its own id that you generate. What criteria you use to sort would be up to you. But let's say you were to use objectID. The you would get the array as I mentioned above and then get a sorted copy like this: 
NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"objectID" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedArray = [answersArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptor:sd];

Comment: I have not tried  NSSortDescriptor *sd = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"objectID" ascending:YES]; yet. are you sure it can be used to sort (same as SQL PK)? or I can test it later

Comment: I don't know much about SQL. So, I can't speak to that comparison. But, yes, this is how I sort collections.

Answer (score 3):

You can sort based on the internal object ID, but that sorting will be arbitrary, because there is no inherent ordering (like time of entry).

If you want ordering to be based on the order it was inserted, there are several options.

Unfortunately, you really didn't specify your real goal, so it's hard to point you into the best direction.

If you only want to access objects based on the order in which they were inserted, you can use an ordered set.  Simply have a "root" object that has a 1-to-many relationship to all your objects.  Check the "ordered" box for the model.

Now, you can simply add objects to that relationship.  It will maintain their order, and you will not pay too much performance because you are not constantly re-ordering them.

Or, you could use a fine grained timestamp, and add that to each object as it is inserted.  Then, sort based on that... it will give you the objects in the order in which they were inserted.

Or, you could just use a simple counter.  Load the counter object from the database.  Give the new object the current value of the counter, and increment the counter for each new object.  You could put a category on your managed object class to create your objects, and it could automatically do the ID creation.

Loads of solutions to your problem... depending on what you want to actually accomplish.

Oh yeah...  Currently, ordered relationships are not supported for iCloud...

Comment: I am interested in this

**You can sort based on the internal object ID, but that sorting will be arbitrary, because there is no inherent ordering (like time of entry).** 
My Real Goal is 
I have four answers for one question， When I initialize(insert)the answers for the question , they are ordered, just like A,B,C,D or 1,2,3,4. if there is an auto-increment id, I can use it to order the answers. But there is not. so I am thinking object ID if it can give me same results.

Comment: No, that will not work.  You need to use one of the other methods and do it yourself.  If you want ordering, why not have a relationship in each question to the answers, and then have that relationship be ordered?  Sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

Use a sort descriptor with `self` as the sort key. The underlying SQL will have `ORDER BY t0.Z_PK`, `Z_PK` being the internal ID of the record (as found as the last component of the object's `NSManagedObjectID`).